# Как передвинуть элемент HTML через функцию JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пишу страницу HTML. Код страницы, исполняемый js-код и код стилей в трех разных папках:

- `site.html`
- `script/script.js`
- `res/style.css`

В HTML присутствуют два элемента:

```
<div class="red"  id="sqr1">       
  <img src="res/blue_square.png">       
</div>

...

<div>
  <input type="button" onclick="move_sqr('sqr1')" value="сдвиг"/>
</div>
```

Код стиля "red":

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.red{
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}
```

С помощью кода js хочу при нажатии кнопки сдвигать данное изображение вправо, увеличивая параметр left родительского элемента div. Непосредственно код:

```
function move_sqr(elem){
  var square = document.getElementById(elem);
  square.style.left = parseInt(square.style.left) + 30 + 'px';
}
```

Данная функция была взята из интернета, разобрана на мельчайшие частицы, но заставить ее работать я не смог.
Из того, что я понял, `square` и `square.style` являются `[object HTMLDivElement]` и `[object CSSStyleDeclaration]` соответственно, однако `square.style.left` является пустым значением и `div` не сдвигается.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Comment: попробуйте либо aбсолютное позиционирование, либо меняйте у элемента square.style.transform='translate(30px,0);

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSW: по совету @StrangerintheQ изменил способ передвижения блока:

```
square.style.left = parseInt(square.style.left) + 30 + 'px';
```

заменил на:

```
tr += 30;
square.style.transform=`translate(${tr}px,0)`;
```

предварительно инициализируя `tr=0`

P.S. Почему `square.style.left` является нулевым - все еще непонятно.
P.S.S @yar85 ниже прекрасно расписал все подробно

Answer (score 2):

Свойство `style` DOM-объекта элемента, является интерфейсом доступа к его индивидуальным, инлайн-стилям.
То есть, к тем стилям, что изначально прописаны инлайном в *атрибуте* `style` в разметке элемента. Например:

```js
const style = document.querySelector('#test').style; 
console.log(`style.left равно значению '${style.left}'`); 
console.log(`style.top равно значению '${style.top}'`);
```

```css
#test { position: relative; top: 50px; left: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="test" style="left: 30px;"></div>
```

Обрати внимание, что в примере `style.top` содержит "ничего", пустую строку - хотя в общей CSS прописано значение `50px`. Это та же "проблема", что и в вопросе. Так происходит как раз потому, что `style` ссылается на инлайновые стили самого элемента, а не на подходящее ему правило в CSSOM (объектной модели "общих" стилей).

---

Вариантом решения задачи из вопроса, может быть такое выражение:

```
square.style.left = (parseInt(square.style.left) || 0) + 30 + 'px';
```

Таким образом, если инлайном стилевое свойство не задано - вместо его значения будет подставлено `0`, оператором `||` (логическое ИЛИ).

---

А для получения *вычисленных* (computed) стилей элемента, следует использовать глобальный метод `getComputedStyle` - он возвращает живой объект (то есть, значения в нем обновляются динамически):

```js
const el = document.querySelector('#test'), 
      cs = getComputedStyle(el); 
console.log(`изначально, вычисленное значение top равно '${cs.top}'`); 
el.style.top = '25px'; 
console.log(`а после изменения style.top - равно значению '${cs.top}'`);
```

```css
#test { position: relative; top: 50px; left: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="test" style="left: 30px;"></div>
```

Односложные свойства доступны через точку, как показано в примере. Для чтения из вычисленных стилей тех свойств, которые состоят из нескольких слов через дефис (например, `box-shadow`), можно применять нотации `compStyles['box-shadow']`, `compStyles.boxShadow`, или использовать специально предназначенный для этого метод `getPropertyValue`:

```
compStyles.getPropertyValue('box-shadow')
```

Вычисленные стили доступны только для чтения.
Для неинициализированных явно css-свойств, вычисленное значение 
будет не пустой строкой, а либо стандартным значением по-умолчанию, либо значением из встроенных стилей браузера (это обязательно следует помнить).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> square.style.left = parseInt(square.style.left) + 30 + 'px';
> ```

```
square.style.left = parseInt(getComputedStyle(square).left) + 30 + 'px';
```